# mysql: Search for records where two columns match another record and specify conditions on both records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a recurring_bill table which describes a subscription transaction. I have some duplicates that have the same customerId and chargeId. I want to identify these duplicate records. I also want to make sure IsDeleted is false for both records and the LastDay is in the future or NULL (so its an ongoing charge). My current query shows records that do not have a duplicate. Please help me correct my query.

```
SELECT * FROM recurring_bills b1
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM recurring_bill b2 WHERE b1.customerId = b2.customerId
    AND b1.chargeId = b2.chargeId
    AND (b2.LastDay > '2022-03-10' OR b2.LastDay IS NULL)
    AND b2.IsDeleted = 0) 
  AND (b1.LastDay > '2022-03-10' OR b1.LastDay IS NULL) AND b1.IsDeleted = 0;
```

Lets say this is the input

```
customerId    |    chargeId       |    LastDay    |    IsDeleted
1             |    charge1        |    NULL       |        0
1             |    charge1        |    05-23-2022 |        0 
2             |    charge2        |    05-23-2022 |        0
2             |    charge2        |    05-23-2021 |        0
3             |    charge3        |    NULL       |        1
3             |    charge3        |    NULL       |        0
```

The correct output would be

```
customerId    |    chargeId       |    LastDay    |    IsDeleted
1             |    charge1        |    NULL       |        0
```

MySQL version is 5.5.59

Comment: 1) What's your MySQL version? 2) It always helps in answering questions to post the table structure and sample of the data (as text). Not all of the columns, just the ones referenced in the query [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3) Post an example of the expected results, using the sample data

Comment: Also, mixing AND/OR operators without the proper parentheses may result in the expressions being evaluated in a different order than expected.

Comment: ... another reason we need to see the table structure is the table probably has a unique key that can be used to differentiate between the "duplicate" records, but that's not included in the query.

Comment: MySQL version is 5.5.59

Comment: Please post the table structure, sample data and an example of the expected results (as text)

Comment: posted the table structure. There is a unique id which is a string also. The "duplicates" don't need to be exact duplicates I just want to find records where there are multiple with the same customerId and chargeId

Comment: Thank you, that makes it much easier to provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using EXISTS to identify records with the same customerId, chargeId, etc.. but having a different unique record Id. (I didn't know the name of your column, so used "TheUniqueId" for the example).

*Note, when mixing AND/OR operators you must use parentheses to ensure expressions are evaluated in the expected order. Otherwise, the query may return the wrong results.*

That said, wouldn't you want to see *all* of the "duplicates", so you could take action on them, if needed? If so, try:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE recurring_bills
>     (`theUniqueId` int auto_increment primary key
>      , `customerId` int
>      , `chargeId` varchar(7)
>      , `LastDay` date
>      , `IsDeleted` int
> )
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO recurring_bills
>     (`customerId`, `chargeId`, `LastDay`, `IsDeleted`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'charge1', NULL, 0),
>     (1, 'charge1', '2022-05-23', 0),
>     (2, 'charge2', '2022-05-23', 0),
>     (2, 'charge2', '2021-05-23', 0),
>     (3, 'charge3', NULL, 1),
>     (3, 'charge3', NULL, 0)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> -- Show all duplicates
> SELECT * 
> FROM   recurring_bills dupe
> WHERE dupe.IsDeleted = 0
> AND ( dupe.LastDay > '2022-03-10' OR
>       dupe.LastDay IS NULL 
>     )
> AND EXISTS (
>     SELECT NULL
>     FROM   recurring_bills b
>     WHERE b.customerId = dupe.customerId
>     AND   b.chargeId   = dupe.chargeId 
>     AND   b.IsDeleted  = dupe.IsDeleted 
>     AND   b.theUniqueId <> dupe.theUniqueId
>     AND ( b.LastDay > '2022-03-10' OR 
>           b.LastDay IS NULL 
>         )
> )
> ```

**Results:**

> ```
> theUniqueId | customerId | chargeId | LastDay    | IsDeleted
> ----------: | ---------: | :------- | :--------- | --------:
>           1 |          1 | charge1  | null       |         0
>           2 |          1 | charge1  | 2022-05-23 |         0
> ```

**If for some reason you really want a single record per chargeId + customerId, add a GROUP BY**

> ```
> -- Show single record per dupe combination
> SELECT * 
> FROM   recurring_bills dupe
> WHERE dupe.IsDeleted = 0
> AND ( dupe.LastDay > '2022-03-10' OR
>       dupe.LastDay IS NULL 
>     )
> AND EXISTS (
>     SELECT NULL
>     FROM   recurring_bills b
>     WHERE b.customerId = dupe.customerId
>     AND   b.chargeId   = dupe.chargeId 
>     AND   b.IsDeleted  = dupe.IsDeleted 
>     AND   b.theUniqueId <> dupe.theUniqueId
>     AND ( b.LastDay > '2022-03-10' OR 
>           b.LastDay IS NULL 
>         )
> )   
>  
> GROUP BY dupe.customerId, dupe.chargeId
> ```

**Results:**

> ```
> theUniqueId | customerId | chargeId | LastDay | IsDeleted
> ----------: | ---------: | :------- | :------ | --------:
>           1 |          1 | charge1  | null    |         0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1866cb9a644e308e11a8d04cb99942c9)*

Comment: Oops had a typo, see updated answer

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks for taking the time to update the question with more details (:

Comment: BTW, to avoid specifying the literal date string in two places, you could probably change this line `AND ( b.LastDay > '2022-03-10' OR .....`  to this instead `AND ( b.LastDay >= dupe.LastDay OR ....`